# How to manage multiple splashscreens in SWT, Java

Tags: java, swt, splash-screen

I have some splashscreens in my SWT written application.
Some of them provide feedback, some provide usercontrolls.

I need to display those splashscreens in a different order.

E.g.:

1. Logo splashscreen
2. Connecting... screen
3. Login-usercontrols screen
4. Logging in... screen

etc.

**Question:**

What is the usual way to manage the screens.
Is there a design pattern, which allows to effectively show a new screen / hide all previous screens?

Comment: That is an interesting question and I would like to know the answer to it. However I am afraid it is not precise enough to catch an attention it is worth. At least not on stackoverflow. You should try programmers.stackexchange.com or make a question more precise.

Comment: I will wait some hours and then skip to programmers.stackexchange.com, and send you the link

Comment: Programmers.SE redirected poor the guy back here. ;) Maybe ux.stackexchage.com  is the best fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just one Window visible at a time, SWTs `StackLayout` might be the right choice for you. Basically, all the screens are within one window, and the StackLayout shows just one of them.